# How to get an error message out of an NSError of Firebase auth login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When i try to print the readable, userfrendly error message of firebase user login, i found i cannot use `NSError.localizedDiscreption` casue it will show "find more in details".

And my Error message looks like this, when i use `print(error)` command

```
2016-05-23 21:29:33.035 Mission Board[3251:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled

Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1277e2bb0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey=<CFBasicHash 0x1288eec60 [0x1a172a150]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,

entries =>

    0 : <CFString 0x12890ad60 [0x1a172a150]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x1288eec20 [0x1a172a150]>{contents = "INVALID_EMAIL"}

    1 : errors = <CFArray 0x12890ad20 [0x1a172a150]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (

    0 : <CFBasicHash 0x12890c660 [0x1a172a150]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,

entries =>

    0 : reason = invalid

    1 : message = <CFString 0x128872790 [0x1a172a150]>{contents = "INVALID_EMAIL"}

    2 : domain = global

}



)}

    2 : code = <CFNumber 0xb000000000001903 [0x1a172a150]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}

}

}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})
```

which is not very readable but i found in entries 1 code 0, there is a message with content "INVALID EMAIL"

Can i just output that part to the alert to user?

is there any built in function can do that?

Comment: I think you have to threat the error. User can't understand this. If you try different errors, like password weak, e-mail already exists, you will see that the error comes in the same format. Message field has the right cause of error, but in code. You can translate every cause to some error friendly message, or most of it.

Comment: how can i modify it? i mean it is not a string right ?

Comment: I mean adding some switch for each possible message content.
In this case "INVALID_EMAIL" should translate to "Invalid email entered."

Comment: how can i set the cases? i can only get such a long message with the tiny useful info in it, there is no specific error code i can use a switch statement there.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330086/firebase-3-2-0-internal-error-on-create-user, a fix is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is my sign up error control. I use KVNProgress pod for alert.

**Swift3**

```
import KVNProgress

FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextLbl.text!, password: self.passwordTextLbl.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

if error != nil {

    let error2:NSError = error as! NSError

    if error2.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeInvalidEmail.rawValue {

         KVNProgress.showError(withStatus: "Invalid Email", completion: nil)

    }else if error2.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeNetworkError.rawValue {

     KVNProgress.showError(withStatus: "Network Error", completion: nil)

    }else if error2.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeWeakPassword.rawValue {

     KVNProgress.showError(withStatus: "Weak Password", completion: nil)

    }else if error2.code == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse.rawValue {

     KVNProgress.showError(withStatus: "Email Already In Use", completion: nil)

    }


}else{


    // Your code


}

 })
```

You can find other error controls in "FIRAuthErrorCode" such as login error handling.