# Google Firebase Authentication with email and password does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I installed the new SDK of Firebase by Google and I am trying to create a new user using the Authentication SDK. However, I did exactly what the documentation says, but it does not work. Any comments or suggestions?

I have the code for Authentication in RegisterUserViewController.h

In AppDelegate.h I also added the [FIRApp configure] in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions;

Here is the code for RegisterUserViewController.h:

```
#import "RegisterUserViewController.h"
@import FirebaseAuth;
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseMessaging;
@interface RegisterUserViewController ()

@end

@implementation RegisterUserViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)createUserButton:(id)sender {

[[FIRAuth auth] createUserWithEmail:self.emailTextField.text password:self.passwordTextField.text completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error)
{
    if(error == nil)
    {
      NSLog(@"%@", user.email);
      NSLog(@"New user Created!");
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToLogin" sender:nil];
    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
}];
}

@end
```

This is the error I get:

Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo=0x7f98fc4609d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f98fc4cf790 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain error 3.)", error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.}

Comment: What is not working ? What is the error message ?

Comment: This is the error I get: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo=0x7f98fc4609d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f98fc4cf790 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain error 3.)", error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.}

Comment: Fixed the problem I had. I just deleted the GoogleService-Info.List and downloaded a new one and it fixed the problem. Everything works now.

Comment: I have the same issue; debugging shows 17999 error code is coming from remote Firebase, with no any detailed description what exactly happens.

Redownloading GoogleService-Info, and enabling IDM, doesn't help. 

This doesn't describe it at all: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/FIRAuthErrorCode#/c:@E@FIRAuthErrorCode@FIRAuthErrorCodeInternalError

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by activating the Identity Toolkit Api on Google Console [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit/overview?project=YOUR_PROJECT](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit/overview?project=)

Answer (score -2):

Below solution worked for me.

Goto Firebase app and re-download the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Ref: [Related Article](https://medium.com/@puthnith/firebase-for-ios-invalid-api-key-cdde76ff92c4)