# Internal error FIRAuthErrorCodeInternalError 17999

Tags: objective-c, firebase, google-signin

For some reason sign in using FireBase shows internal error. It was working fine and it is showing the error now.

I followed this fix from this URL.
[Google Firebase Authentication with email and password does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634804/google-firebase-authentication-with-email-and-password-does-not-work)

I downloaded Google-Info.plist file from FireBase again and used. Checked if 'Identity ToolKit Api' is enabled in my project and it is enabled.

I have updated the API using pod update and result as same "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."

This is the code I used to sign in from FireBase. It was working good till yesterday.

```
[ [ FIRAuth auth ] signInWithEmail:email
                          password:password
                        completion:^(FIRUser* user, NSError* error)
 {

 } ];
```

Did anybody else face this issue and was able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I commented old pod to new line in my project Podfile.

```
# pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

'$ pod update' in terminal on the location of my project.

With this the version updated hugely from Firebase 3.17.0 to Firebase 6.3.0.
Now I am able to sign in successfully without internal error.